# IOS/Objective-C: Manipulate dimensions of arrays

Tags: ios, nsarray

In order to search two entities in Core Data, I would like to create an array drawn from both. It is easy to create an array of objects from one entity and also to create an array with just one attribute using valueforkey.  You can combine single attribute arrays into one long one using arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray.  However, I need to create two attribute arrays from each entity that include the name and id.

Does anyone know of a way to drop attributes or fields as you can do in R or many other languages so I can create arrays with just two attributes that can then be added together?

The starting arrays have different numbers of attributes i.e.

```
cars({
        make = "Ford";
        model = "Focus";
        year = "2010";
        carid = 127;
    },
        {
       make = "Chevy";
        model = "Camaro";
        year = "2014";
        carid = 126;
        })
 bikes({
        make = "Giant";
        year = "2010";
        bikeid = 33;
    },
        {
       make = "Trek";
        year = "2014";
        bikeid = 34;
        })
```

Using value for key as in:

```
NSMutableArray * carmakes = [[cars valueForKey:@"make"] mutableCopy];
```

I can convert the arrays to

```
cars(
    "Ford",
    "Chevy",
    "Toyota")

bikes(
    "Giant",
    "Trek",
    "Cannondale")
```

And using:

```
vehicles=[_bikes arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:_cars];
```

combine these to:

```
vehicles(
"Giant",
    "Ford",
    "Chevy",
    "Toyota",
    "Giant",
    "Trek",
    "Cannondale")
```

However, there are no ids.  How can I create an array that looks like:

```
vehicles({
        make = "Ford";
       id = 127;
    },
        {
       make = "Chevy";
        id = 126;
         },
        {
       make = "Giant";
        id = 33; },
        {
       make = "Trek";
        id = 34;})
```

**Edit:**

Here is how the properties appear in their managed object files:

```
@interface Cars : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * carid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * make;
@end
```

The array is created from the following code:

```
   NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Cars"];
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

    NSError *error      = nil;
    self.managedObjectContext = [Model sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;

    NSArray *results    = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                   error:&error];
    NSMutableArray* cars = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:results];

    return cars;
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to overthink it too much. Create a method to combine the two arrays.

**UPDATE**

From the error you got, I can see that you don't have arrays of dictionaries, but CoreData entities. Without knowing the entities in play, this is just guessing. I'm going to work with `Cars`, `Bikes`, but return a dictionary. You may need to update this to work with a `Vehicles` entity.

```
- (NSArray *)arrayByCombiningCars:(NSArray *)cars bikes:(NSArray *)bikes {
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:cars.count + bikes.count];

    for (Cars *car in cars) {
        NSAssert(car.make && car.carid, @"car must have a make and cardid.");
        NSDictionary *vehicle = @{@"make":car.make, @"id": car.carid};
        [result addObject:vehicle];
    }

    for (Bikes *bike in bikes) {
        NSAssert(bike.make && bike.bikeid, @"bike must have a make and bikeid.");
        NSDictionary *vehicle = @{@"make":bike.make, @"id": bike.bikeid};
        [result addObject:vehicle];
    }

    return [result copy];
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Simple once you have explained it. Thank you.

Comment: Thought this would work, but am getting error on car[@"make"] of 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Cars objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance .  Make is an attribute.  Error also happens when I just try to log car[@"make"]. Is it possible that the array does not consist of dictionaries or what could be wrong?

Comment: This is what I get when I log car: <Cars: 0x6080000d6650> (entity: Cars; id: 0xd000000002dc0000 <x-coredata://272E5041-B809-4A02-80E7-D579192689D9/Cars/p183> ; data: {
    make = “Ford";
    carid = 6729;
    timecreated = nil;
    wasdeleted = nil;
})

Comment: Oh wait this is core data stuff. Please update the question with the needed types. Cars, Bikes, and Vehicles (if needed).

Comment: When you say types do you mean data types? Make is an NSString and carid and bikeid are NSNumbers.

Comment: What is the full interface for `Cars`? Is there an interface for `Bikes`? If so, what if that full interface? Is there a class which has `make` and `id` (like Vehicles or something such)? If so, what is the full interface for that?

Comment: There is a class for cars and for bikes--see above. There is no class for vehicles as it is just a synthetic array created to search cars and bikes at same time.

Comment: The first part of the method is now working but it is throwing same error as before on bike.make in the second part.  Could there be an issue with the fact that I am working with mutableArrays?  I changed your method to - (NSMutableArray *)arrayByCombiningCars:(NSMutableArray *)cars bikes:(NSMutableArray *)bikes  as the properties are NSMutableArrays due to other stuff going on in the view controller.

Comment: Found error in how I was creating bike.  Your answer is correct.